# SwiftUI Nav Bar cut off

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I recently updated Xcode and for some reason now in the simulator (and on device) my nav bars on my SwiftUI views are cut off like the below image:
[image]

I didn't change any of my code so I am wondering what the heck happened. Code of this view for reference is below:

```swift
struct EventsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EventsViewModel

    init() {
        viewModel = EventsViewModel()
        coloredNavAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()

        coloredNavAppearance.backgroundColor = ColorCodes.darkGrey.uicolor()
        coloredNavAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        coloredNavAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredNavAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredNavAppearance

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none

    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if viewModel.eventViewModels.isEmpty {
                ZStack {
                    ColorCodes.darkGrey.color()
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    VStack {
                    Text("No events are active yet. Click the plus button to purchase an event.").foregroundColor(.white).font(.custom("Segoe UI", size: 17))
                    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Active Events"), displayMode: .large)
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                        Button(action:  {
                            //show add event modal
                            self.viewModel.showAddEventModal.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image("plus")
                        }
                    )
                }

            }else {
                List{

                    ForEach(viewModel.eventViewModels, id: \.id) { eventViewModel in
                        EventRow(viewModel: eventViewModel)
                    }.listRowBackground(ColorCodes.darkGrey.color())
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Active Events"), displayMode: .large)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button(action:  {
                        //show add event modal
                        self.viewModel.showAddEventModal.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                )
                .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(viewModel.errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showAddEventModal) {
                    AddEventView(viewModel: AddEventViewModel())
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what an event looks like:

```swift
struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {

    public let id: String
    public let name: String
    public let phoneNumber: PhoneNumber
    public let isActive: Bool
    public let startDate: Date



    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case phoneNumber = "event_phone_number"
        case startDate = "start"
    }

}
```

Here is the events view model:

```swift
import Combine

enum EventViewModelState {
    case loading
    case finishedLoading
    case error(Error)
}

class EventsViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var eventViewModels: [EventCellViewModel] = []

    @Published private(set) var state: EventViewModelState = .loading

    @Published var errorMessage: String = ""

    @Published var showAlert: Bool = false

    @Published var showAddEventModal: Bool = false

    private var getEventsCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    private let eventService: EventServiceProtocol

    init(eventService: EventServiceProtocol = EventService()) {
        self.eventService = eventService
        getEvents()
    }

    func getEvents() {
        state = .loading

        getEventsCancellable = eventService
            .getEvents()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] (completion) in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let serviceError):
                    if let errorCasted = serviceError as? ServiceError {
                    self?.unWrapError(error: errorCasted)
                    self?.state = .error(serviceError)
                    self?.showAlert = true
                    }
                case .finished: self?.state = .finishedLoading
                }
            }) { [weak self] events in
                self?.eventViewModels = events.map {
                    EventCellViewModel(event: $0)
                }
        }
    }

    func unWrapError(error: ServiceError) {
        switch error {
        case .url:
            self.errorMessage = "There was something wrong with the url request, please contact support."
        case .urlRequest:
             self.errorMessage = "There was something wrong with the url request, please contact support."
        case .decode:
             self.errorMessage = "There was something wrong with the response. Please make sure you are on the latest version of the app or contact support."
        case .internalError(let errorString):
             self.errorMessage = errorString
        }
    }
}
```

here is the event cell view model:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class EventCellViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var eventPhoneNumber: String = ""
    @Published var startDate: String = ""
    @Published var id: String = ""

    private let event: Event

    init(event: Event) {
        self.event = event
        setUpBindings()
    }

    func setUpBindings() {
        id = String(event.id)
        name = event.name
        eventPhoneNumber = event.phoneNumber.phoneNumber
        startDate = event.startDate.toShortDate()
    }
}
```

I do have some custom nav bar appearance settings set in the init of the class but this was working perfectly before. did this happen to anyone else and did anyone find or figure out a workaround? Also since there is one item here as you can see below, it's going into the else block of my view not the if where you see the ZStack so that isn't the issue as I and others previously thought before. I have also tried completely removing that part but this still happens.

Comment: Would you provide minimal reproducible example, `cause provided snapshot is not testable as-is, so what might work for me would not work for you.

Comment: updated my example to include more details/supporting classes @Asperi

Comment: Also it's worth noting that preview mode in Xcode does display it correctly but it does not display correctly in simulator or on device.

Answer (score 0):

does this fix your problem:

```
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action:  {
                    //show add event modal
                    self.viewModel.showAddEventModal.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            )
```

Comment: sadly no it does not :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Somehow this line

```swift
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

was added onto my tab view and causing all of the problems.